# What is the exact CPU / Network capacity for 1 ACU of RDS Serverless v1/v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

[AWS RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rds/index.html) Serverless [v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v1.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.architecture) / [v2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.capacity) doc states that 1 ACU *(Aurora capacity unit*) is

> a combination of approximately **2 gibibytes (GiB) of memory, corresponding CPU, and networking**

It's clear enough about memory, but what does "*corresponding CPU, and networking*" mean exactly? Is there any way to know more precisely what performance we shall expect in term or CPU, Network and IO ?